# How to add LESS files to a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, less

I can't seem to get this to work in my rails app. At a high level, I wan't to use LESS in my app and have it go through the asset pipeline.

This is what my assets look like:

```
assets
|
|--- javascript
|
|--- stylesheets
            |
            |-- reset.less
            |-- my-mixins.less
            |-- my-variables.less
            |-- base.less
|
|--- images
|
|--- libs
        |
        |---foo
            |
            |--css
                |
                |--- foo-mixins.less
                |
                |--- bar.less
```

I would like to import "my-mixins.less", "my-variables.less" and "foo-mixins.less" into "base.less", as well as other files. "bar.less" should also be added to specific pages if needed.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

This should work, assuming you're using the less-rails gem.

First, add this to somewhere in your configuration (I have mine in my environment.rb):

```
YourApp::Application.configure do
  config.less.paths << File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets', 'less')
end
```

Now, if you have a file setup like this:

```
assets
|
|--- javascript
|
|--- css
|        |--- site-stylesheet.css.less
|
|--- less
         |--- my-mixins.less
```

You can import my-mixins in site-stylesheet by using:

```
@import "my-mixins"
```

And import the stylesheet into your app with:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "site-stylesheet" %>
```

You should be able to extrapolate from there for your specific directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

In base.css.less you can write `@import "my-variables.less";` and it should work.

Comment: that's what I thought but it doesn't appear to work. I'll try it again for the hell of it.

Answer (score 0):

The files have to be in the "vendor/assets" or "vendor/plugins" (both at the root level) folder in order to reference them with relative paths.